# Cross browser editable span

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, margin, html-input

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZE35u/) is a simple example of editable span element.

Span element can be edited by clicking on lt - input appears.

```
<span>Hello</span>
<input type="text" style="display:none;" value=""/>
<style>
    span, input {    
        font-family: arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    span {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("span").click(function() {
            $(this).hide();
            $("input").val($(this).text()).show();
        });
        $("input").keypress(function(e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                $(this).hide();
                $("span").text($(this).val()).show();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I want the text in input to be in the exact position as the text in span.

So I'm adding the margins:

For Chrome:

```
input {
    margin-left: -2px;
    margin-top: -2px;
}
```

For IE 10 and Opera:

```
input {
    margin-left: -3px;
    margin-top: -2px;
}
```

For Firefox:

```
input {
    margin-left: -4px;
    margin-top: -2px;
}
```

Can I make a universal css which works in any browser without any special tricks?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `contenteditable` attribute should work for you. It works [all the way back to ie5.5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable).

`<span contenteditable></span>`

http://jsfiddle.net/CCJMe/

Comment: Thanks for your reply! How could I make in to behave like an input without going to a new line when the span width ends?

Comment: Should be able to add `white-space: nowrap;` to the span.

Comment: It will break the span width anyway.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to do it with [the only input element](http://jsfiddle.net/chCsS/) but your solution seems easier.

Comment: This is by far the best solution! Native support. Would use something different for Angular, to bind to a controller variable.